# Blender 3.3 Hair - how to set random hair length with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair

I'm still not very familiar with Geometry Nodes and can not figure out how to control individual hair length with them in the new Blender 3.3 Hair system. I've added a new hair object and added some straight hairs in the sculpt mode. Now I want to be able to randomize their length with Geometry Nodes without affecting their direction. I haven't found any node like "Scale Curves" or "Scale Splines", while Scale Elements and Scale Instances nodes don't work with Hair Curves. Transform node affects the whole object. I tried following approaches:

At first I tried to directly Set Position of the hair tips using Noise Texture with indices as X coordinates, but it just randomly moves hair tips all around. I understand the reason but it is not what I am looking for:
[image]
I tried multiplying normals with noise which worked fine for the mesh displacement but I'm not even sure what the normals are for the hair curves. At least it doesn't work:
[image]
I tried to capture Normals from the mesh object as a Named Attribute in all modes to use this attribute as vectors in the Hair Geometry Nodes, but it doesn't affect anything:
[image]
I tried to fix Hair Normal rotation angle but failed:
[image]
I am out of ideas of how to control length of individual hairs. Can anyone help with this please?

UDD.
Uploaded [.blend file](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/aB0sFA313FsqRQ) with all 4 Geometry Nodes data blocks in it.

Comment: Could you share your blend file so we don't have to recreate it all? ...because you could just scale the normal vector.

Comment: @quellenform thanks, I've uploaded project file, and added a link to the post. How do I get a proper normal vector to scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scale the hair differently along the normals of the surface, you can use the following solution:

[image]

Here I use `Object Info` and `Transfer Attribute` to bring in the normal of the sphere, and scale this direction vector with a randomly generated value.

But so that only the endpoint of the curves is affected, I use the node `Endpoint Selection` as selection when moving the points.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.3+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.